# How to check if a certain row exists in a c# dictionary depending on declared types

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Let's say that I've created a list that has a dictionary inside its members.

```
    List<FieldValues> fieldValues = new List<FieldValues>()
{
    new FieldValues(tableFields[0]) {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {0, "" },
            {1, "" }
        }

    },
    new FieldValues(tableFields[1]) {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {0, "x" },
            {1, "x" }
        }

    },
    new FieldValues(tableFields[2]) {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {0, "x" },
            {1, "x" }
        }

    },
    new FieldValues(tableFields[3])  {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {0, "Car" },
            {1, "Travel" }
        }

    },
};
```

Note that I created classes **FieldValues:Fields** like this:

```
enum FieldType
{
    Boolean,
    Integer,
    String
}

class Fields
{
    public FieldType type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    //declar fields(columns) name and types (types should be as in mysql syntax)
    public string GetFieldDeclaration()
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case FieldType.Boolean:
                return name + " tinyint(1)";
            case FieldType.Integer:
                return name + " int";
            case FieldType.String:
                return name + " varchar(2048)";
            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}

class FieldValues:Fields
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> dictionary { get; set; }

    //in order to add a new field value of the respected field
    public FieldValues(Fields field)
    {
        type = field.type;
        name = field.name;
        dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    }


    public void AddToDictionary(int row, string cellValue)                             
    {

        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(row))
        {
            dictionary[row] = cellValue; 
        }
        else
        {
            dictionary.Add(row, cellValue); //else adaug randul la tabela
        }
    }

    public string GetRowValue(int row)
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(row))
        {
            if()
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }


}
```

All this I will use to insert an excel spreadsheet values into mysql database like this:

```
string createQuery2 = createQuery + "\n INSERT INTO `poi_specs_mgu_ece_1.6` (";

        for (var i = 0; i < tableFields.Count; i++)
        {
            createQuery2 += "\n\t" + tableFields[i].GetFieldDeclaration() + (i == tableFields.Count - 1 ? string.Empty : ",");
        }
        createQuery2 += ")\n VALUES ( ";


        for (var i = 0; i < fieldValues.Count; i++)
        {

            createQuery2 += "\n\t" + fieldValues[i].dictionary[0] + fieldValues[i].dictionary[1];
        }
        createQuery2 += " \n);";
```

and I want to create a method inside FieldValues class, GetRowValue(), that checks if a certain row is present in dictionary, depending on this, i will now which type of values should be inserted and it seems i am stuck on this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Um, are you just looking for `return dictionary[row]`?  This has to be the most incomprehensible homework assignment I have ever seen.

Comment: I want to check what type i should insert on a certain row in each field.
"fields" are interpreted as excel columns, where a column can be of different types: int, boolean(tinyint(1)) or string. 
I want to check if a dictionary has the row, and if it does, I want to determine which type of values can be inserted in each field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string GetRowValue(int row)
{
    string result;
    if(!dictionary.TryGetValue(row, out result))
        result = "";
    return result;
}
```